# Material React Table with searchable dropdown

Tags: autocomplete, material-react-table

I am using material react table for my project.
I have a column with dropdown list.
But I need to have autocomplete or searchable dropdown inside a Material React Table column.
Please refer this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/KevinVandy/material-react-table/tree/main/apps/material-react-table-docs/examples/editing-crud/sandbox?file=/src/TS.tsx) from the official [example](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/editing-crud)

```js
  const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
    () => [
      // ...
      {
        accessorKey: 'state',
        header: 'State',
        muiTableBodyCellEditTextFieldProps: {
          select: true, //change to select for a dropdown
          children: states.map((state) => (
            <MenuItem key={state} value={state}>
              {state}
            </MenuItem>
          )),
        },
      },
    ],
    [getCommonEditTextFieldProps],
  );
```

I want [select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#select) with search option.

Comment: I search the entire project of material-react-table, it seems impossible to use AutoComplete component in the edit mode because it is [hard coded](https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/tree/main/packages/material-react-table/src/inputs) to  use TextField for the [edit field of every cell](https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/blob/a52cdc907f2771f5c194643cf132254f84387689/packages/material-react-table/src/body/MRT_EditRowModal.tsx#L43). You can submit a [feature request](https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/issues) to Kevin on Github.

Comment: Ok Sure. I will submit the same .

Answer (score 0):

I think for Autocomplete would be something like this:
where the autoComplete option will filter the values based on the input as you type, at least in JS it works for me:

```
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

...

{
    accessorKey: 'state', header: 'State',
    Edit: ({row})=> 
        {return <Autocomplete
                options={states}
                autoComplete
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="State" />}
                onChange={(event, value) => {row._valuesCache['state'] = value ; } } />;
        } 
}
```